# How to check MySql access in java

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

Is there any way to diagnose a big java application that where we have used MYSql database access in different classes or in other words how i could know that which classes accessing database in any aspect??

Thanks

Comment: Based on your reply to Scientist, you should clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a sample java application for checking the mysql connectivity in java .

The code will be as follows:-

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
dataSource.setUser("scott");
dataSource.setPassword("tiger");
dataSource.setServerName("myDatabaseHost.example.org");
and then obtain connections from it, same as above:

Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM USERS");
...
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

If you are able to execute the query successfully you will be able to know whether mysql connectivity is there or not.

Comment: Comment out the comments ;)

Comment: Actually this is not my question, i am asking how i could know that which classes accessing database or using data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the easiest way to do this would be to pass in a String parameter of the calling class into the factory method that returns your database connection.

Other than that, the only other thing you would be able to use as far as I know is 
`Thread.getAllStackTraces()`, though that seems like it would be an expensive option just to log a class name.